# How to set checkbuttons to display a word in a label when enough checkbuttons are clicked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make checkbuttons display a sentence on a label when three of the checkbuttons are clicked.
New to tkinter, here's what I have tried so far.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Check_button_one = IntVar()
Check_button_two = IntVar()
Check_button_three = IntVar()

Checkbutton(root, variable = Check_button_one).pack()
Checkbutton(root, variable = Check_button_two).pack()
Checkbutton(root, variable = Check_button_three).pack()

default_text = ""
updated_text = "what a legend you are!"

while Check_button_one == 1 and Check_button_two == 1 and Check_button_three == 1:
    default_text = updated_text

Label_main = Label(root, text = default_text)
Label_main.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is a lot of good advice in @martineau's answer (mainloop(), how to change the label's text), I think the polling approach is not suitable for a GUI application.

Assuming that the CheckButtons are (de)activated by the user (via mouse/keyboard)*****, you *do not* want to regularly check their states. When polling in intervals, you have two problems:

- No immediate response to user action: in the worst case, the label's text will only be updated after the interval, i.e. if the interval is 500ms, the label could change 500ms after the checkbutton was clicked.
- Most of the time, your code does unnecessarily check the button states although they haven't changed

The correct way to handle user interaction is specifying a callback that is executed whenever the CheckButton's state has changed as a result of a user action. CheckButton takes a `command` parameter for that purpose:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Check_button_one = IntVar()
Check_button_two = IntVar()
Check_button_three = IntVar()

default_text = ""
updated_text = "what a legend you are!"
Label_main = Label(root, text = default_text)
Label_main.pack()

def checkbuttonCallback():
    if Check_button_one.get() and Check_button_two.get() and Check_button_three.get():
        Label_main.config(text=updated_text)
    else:
        Label_main.config(text=default_text)

Checkbutton(root, variable = Check_button_one, command=checkbuttonCallback).pack()
Checkbutton(root, variable = Check_button_two, command=checkbuttonCallback).pack()
Checkbutton(root, variable = Check_button_three, command=checkbuttonCallback).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

***** If you change the CheckButtons' states via code, you can simply check the states after you changed them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to periodically check the status of the `Buttons` while the GUI `mainloop()` is running. You can do that in a `tkinter` app by using the universal widget [`after`](http://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method.

For example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Check_button_one = IntVar()
Check_button_two = IntVar()
Check_button_three = IntVar()

Checkbutton(root, variable = Check_button_one).pack()
Checkbutton(root, variable = Check_button_two).pack()
Checkbutton(root, variable = Check_button_three).pack()

default_text = ""
updated_text = "what a legend you are!"

Label_main = Label(root, text=default_text)
Label_main.pack()

def check_buttons():
    if Check_button_one.get() and Check_button_two.get() and Check_button_three.get():
        Label_main.config(text=updated_text)
    else:  # Make sure the default is displayed.
        Label_main.config(text=default_text)

    root.after(500, check_buttons)  # Schedule next check in 500 msecs


check_buttons()  # Start polling buttons.
root.mainloop()
```